# Why is my 6-year-old son yelling or being very loud when talking?

Tags: behavior, primary-schooler, speech

I have a 6-year-old son. Whenever he talks, he yells. He has had several hearing tests and passes them with flying colors. I do not understand why he tends to yell. Is his behavior normal?

Comment: What does his pediatrician think?

Comment: Sometime kids just like to yell.  It's annoying as all get up and go, but it's not necessarily a sign of anything beyond the kid liking loud noises.

Comment: Have you considered a hearing test?

Answer (score 3):

Drawing from experience with my 4 yo and from re-telling from my own childhood by my own mother, it may be that your 6 yo is simply afraid of not being heard?

I know that both my 4yo and my 7yo crank up the volume if I don't answer quickly, in spite of all my best efforts to do so or to teach them some sort of self-control and patience.

Additionally, it may be simply a reaction to his environment or a reproduction of what he sees around him.

You have to put yourself in his context:

- he's small,
- he's aware he's a child and grown-ups have precedence,
- he's oftentimes in noisy surroundings (school playground and class, activities, etc...) where raising his voice gets him heard,
- it's what grown-ups do when they want the kids to pay attention.

In what contexts is he yelling?

- When talking to you?
- To siblings/friends?
- To anyone else, e.g. the baker, the postman. the cashier?
- To himself during "quiet play"?

I'd expect he does mostly in the first 2 contexts, for either or both of the reasons stated above. If it's in all scenarios, all the time... then I don't know.

Also, though I suppose you've done so already, have you tried:

- asking him why he raises his voice,
- and asking him to compare his volume to that of the rest of the room?

Answer (score -1):

It might be interesting to do a sensory profile evaluation.  This could be done with an occupational therapist.  If you'd like to see an intro to this, here is a link: http://www.pearsonclinical.com/therapy/products/100000822/sensory-profile-2.html#tab-training
Especially the last audio item on the list, the 10-minute Framework presentation.